# How to display error message on gitlab merge request page when CI fails?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

### Background

I am validating all commit messages of a merge request once a merge request is created, I am doing that using `.gitlab-ci.yml`, my jobs currently validates commit messages to have timelogs inside then ie. `init project /spend 1h30m`

### Problem

I want to display an error message if CI failed to validate the commit messages of the merge request saying `Error: some commits are missing time logs`

this is what I currently get at the moment, I want to put the error instead of "The pipeline for this merge request failed" or some where in that box

[image]

### Possible Solution

- leave a comment on MR page once webhook triggers failed pipeline
  event

Comment: What if the output from a failed job is, let's say, 20k lines? Right now the errors are just one click away.

Comment: @JakubKania in my particular case the error is one line only

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could write a script to post a comment on the MR (see the relevant documentation: http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#create-new-merge-request-note) with the specific error (make a Bot account, or use your own, and store the API token as a CI Variable), in the GitLab UI itself it isn't possible to do this, though it is an interesting idea.

Feel free to open an issue suggesting it :)

Comment: I written this as a possible solution, but its not what I'm after, because I could end up with a lot of comments if the pipeline failed a couple of times